# How to compare values of two different columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare values of two different columns of a pandas dataframe and returns a boolean list or something using which we could be able to plot a pie chart showing the true or false proposition.

In the below image, I want to compare the toss_winner column and the winner column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2TDE.png

I have tried doing this:

> df['toss_winner'].equals(df['winner'])

but it compares the whole columns. Can someone help me?

Comment: yours almost works, just change `equals()` to [**`eq()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

Comment: Oh that's nice thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `==` operator or `eq` method

```py
df['toss_winner'] == df['winner']
```

**SAMPLE RUN**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0,10,100), "B": np.random.randint(0,10,100)})
df['A'] == df['B']
Out[159]: 
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
      ...  
95    False
96    False
97    False
98    False
99     True
Length: 100, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, never thought it was this simple!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be it:

df['flag'] = df['toss_winner']==df['winner']

Comment: Thanks for answering, never thought it was this simple!